# Restangular javascript typeError stuff.put is not a function, but it is - and it is working too

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, restangular

I have weird "non-error" in my restangular setup. Stuff works fine even though errors are logged to the console.

I use a component driven approach with a decoupled restangular service factory (clientService). The service factory is injected into the controller and bound to `this.clients = clientService;`

In the clientrecord widget's link function I get a specific client and watch for changes to `client.keywords` done by another directive.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    var cid = $stateParams.clientid;
    scope.client = ctrl.clients.one(cid).get().$object;

    scope.$watchCollection('client.keywords', 
        function (newval, oldval, scope) {
            scope.client.put();
        }
    );
}
```

The code works fine. Keywords are edited by the other widget, changes are detected, put requests are made and keywords end up in the database. But both chrome and firefox throw an error:

```
"typeError: scope.client.put" is not a function"
```

At the moment it is just an annoyance, but could it evolve into nasty behaviour further on? Can I fix it? Do I need to typecast something?

The Service itself is basically a one-liner:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('client')
    .factory('clientService', ClientService);
  ClientService.$inject = ['Restangular','$stateParams'];

  function ClientService(Restangular) {
    return Restangular.service('routes/clients');
  }
}());
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? The service at the very least

Comment: @AnidMonsur service factory added above

Answer (score 0):

Try add existence check on `scope.client` in watcher (not good solution):

```
function (newval, oldval, scope) {
    scope.client = scope.client ? scope.client : [];
    scope.client.put();
}
```

or before `scope.client` creating (slightly better solution):

```
scope.client = [];
scope.client = ctrl.clients.one(cid).get().$object;
```

**Update:**
Or (better way), if `ctrl.clients` return [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), create watcher, after data loading. Something like this:

```
ctrl.clients.one(cid).get().then(function(data){
    scope.client = data;
    scope.$watchCollection(/* watcher; */);
});
```

But this is only conjecture, since I do not know `ctrl.clients` structure;

Comment: The first two options didn't change anything. ctrl.clients does return a promise (hence the .$object method to get at the goods), but when I try to resolve the promise, it stops working. Obviously I can't resolve the promise inside the link function. Frankly, I  have no idea when or how the promise gets resolved - it just magically works. I probably need to go over the documentation a few more times ;-)   But thanks for trying!